# eigenvalue solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

If the eigenvalues of a $3x3$ matrix A has $λ_1 = 0$ and $λ_2=5$ (double), then the system Ax=0 has 1.unique solution 2. no solution 3.infinite solutions
which of those 3 is true ?

my approach:

we have something like this:
\begin{bmatrix}0&x&x\\x&5&x\\x&x&5\end{bmatrix}
$rankA=3$
it has not infinite solutions because $rankA=m=n$

i am not sure about the other two, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, because of eigenvalue $0$, there is a one dimensional eigenspace, i.e. a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $A(\mu v)= 0$ for all $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. $(\mu v)_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}}$ constitutes this eigenspace.

Therefore you have an infinite amount of solutions.

And, VERY IMPORTANT! Your matrix absolutely does not have to look like the one you constructed. It is of the form
$$
S
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
S^{-1}
$$
where $S$ is an arbitrary invertible matrix. Play with values of $S$ to see that the diagonal elements of your matrix might be wrong.